# Maximum distance from other points on square

Tags: algorithms

Suppose given a square on plane,  the location of side left-down part is on coordinate(0,0) and right-top part on coordinate (10,10). Now there are points on coordinates $$S=\{(9,4),(5,8),(4,3),(1,7)\}.$$
Now we want move from (0,0) to (10,10) in any direction that remain inside the square, such that on moving from start( from (0,0)) to end (10,10) we have maximum distance from points in $S$. What's maximum distance in way that we go from (0,0) to (10,10) to other points?

Comment: Is any continuous path allowed with real coordinates or do we have to move from integer point to nearby integer point?

Comment: Yes, continuous path is allowed

Comment: Just a hunch but it seems to me that there should be an optimal solution that follows the lines of a Voronoï diagram and the sides of the square. The idea is that if an optimal solution goes inside one of the domains of the diagram, you can push the solution towards the edge of the domain without changing the optimality.

Comment: Are you have an idea to calculate the distance after drawing Voronoï   diagram?

Comment: @Rostami.M Yes I think we can modify Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm to do that. Define the capacity of an edge of the V diagram as the minimum distance to the points along this edge. Then starting from $(0,0)$, define inductively the maximal capacity that can be brought to the vertices of the V diagram. Propagate capacities from the best vertex so far to its neighbors depending on the capacities of the edges. I think it works.